# IVY 2.4 no Subversion resolver available anymore

Tags: svn, ivy, svnkit

I just ran into an issues on my continuous integration machines updating Java, Jenkins and the IVY toolchain: there is no current SVN resolver anymore. My problem: the old Subversion library (IVY-SVN 2.2) used in the older SVN resolver is so outdated, it fails on accessing HTTPS with "unknown cipher" error... it seems like it cannot decode the SSL > SSLv3 from server side anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this one was solved by leaving IVY in version 2.2 and updating the SVNKIT library ONLY. Then all libraries are still compatible and update/commit cycles work with latest versions of Subversion 1.8.x and Java >= 1.8.x and TLS 1.x.

Since this is a temporary solution, I do not mark it as solved. I guess IVY and Subversion are both not "trending" anymore, I seriously recommend update to a GRADLE/MAVEN/GIT combination now.

Comment: Or store your binaries in a artefact repository like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva?

Comment: This would be my solution when going for gradle, but with current IVY features (see older posts of mine), this is simply not possible. IVY allows n x m relationships to be published, whereas Maven is only 1 x n.

Comment: gotcha... Ivy is certainly a more flexible technology, but it just never gained the same level of adoption as a server-side repository technology. You could take a look at Artifactory, I think it supports non-Maven repository formats. This might provide some options. Best of luck!